# QML compass azimuth value to angle rotation

Tags: qt, qml, angle

I am trying to make a compass application using QtSensors 5.0, I am able to get azimuth value from the compass but I can't seem to find a proper formula to convert azimuth into a rotation angle for an image of a compass needle. Would anyone have any idea of what formula I need to use to get a proper rotation angle?

My code below

```
property real readAz: 0
property real angle: 0

Compass {
    id: compass
    dataRate: 1
    active: true

    onReadingChanged: {
        readAz = reading.azimuth
        angle  = (readAz /(2*Math.PI))

        print("Compass: ", reading.azimuth) //for debug
        print("Angle: ", angle)             //for debug

        needle.update()
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Can you explain why you think your code is wrong? Are you having problems with the math part, or some programming related, like the variable does not store the precision properly, etc?

Comment: the angle variable only seems to go up to 57. Here is the some console data from the:


`print("Compass: ", reading.azimuth)`
`print("Angle: ", angle)`


`Angle:  0
Compass:  359

Angle:  57.13662456999043
Compass:  358

Angle:  56.97746962689853
Compass:  357

Angle:  56.81831468380664
Compass:  357

Angle:  56.81831468380664
Compass:  359

Angle:  57.13662456999043
Compass:  10

Angle:  1.5915494309189535
Compass:  36`


and it does not rotate the rectangle I got but readAz value does

Comment: Should you not multiply by 360, or if you convert the azimuth to radian then 3.14? Also, are you not missing the radius in the computation? I.e. angle/360 = azimuth/(2*r*pi).

Comment: I am using 
`transform: Rotation { origin.x: 5; origin.y: 50; axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 } angle: angle}` 

To rotate my rectangle object but it just doesn't work with angle value

Comment: Have you seen my equotion above? Is it the rotation angle unexpected, or the rotation itself does not seem to work in your opinion?

Comment: Have you noticed my questions?